# How to know what partition I need to delete?

Tags: partitioning

I used to use Linux, but I've since walked away from it. Now, I'd like to completely remove the partition that I set for Linux, which is about 200 GB. I'm not entirely sure if that's what it is, but that's what I remember setting.

So, should I just go into my partitions in Windows and delete the 200 GB partition? Or is there any firmer way of telling if it's the correct one? I'm not trying to delete a partition that will wreck my computer, which I hope isn't the case with deleting Linux's partition.

Comment: Showing the partition table from Disk Management or gparted will help other contributors to help you assess which partition need to be removed. If you are using Windows - anything ext3 / ext4 is not useful for you (as they are used exclusively under Linux)

Answer (score 1):

Open Disk Management and check the ***File System*** column. Windows can't recognize Linux file systems so that column should be empty for Linux partitions. Then check the ***Status*** column, the Linux root partition should contain only *Primary* (and optionally *Active*) or *Logical*. It shouldn't contain anything like *Boot, Page File, Crash Dump, EFI System Partition, Recover Partition...*

[image: Disk management screenshot]

But for more confidence you should use some 3<sup>rd</sup> party partitioning tools that understand Linux file systems like [MiniTool Partition Wizard](https://www.partitionwizard.com/), [AOMEI Partition Assistant](https://www.disk-partition.com/free-partition-manager.html), [EaseUS Partition Master](https://www.easeus.com/partition-master/convert-gpt-disk-to-mbr-disk.html), [Macrorit Partition Expert](https://macrorit.com/partition-magic-manager/free-edition.html) or [fixparts](http://www.rodsbooks.com/fixparts/). The Linux root file system is usually ext4 for most users, but depending on how you installed and partitioned it can be other file systems like Btrfs, XFS, F2FS, ZFS... Also check the partition label if any